# How to stop the WebsocketComponent in Apache Camel?

Tags: scala, jetty, apache-camel, akka

The application I am writing use Apache Camel (the camel-websocket component) to create a Web Socket.

The problem is that if I try to stop the Actor (i.e., the Producer in Akka Camel ) I can not stop the Jetty server created as component during the initialization.
I actually try to call the `doStop()` method in the `postStop()` method of my actor but it seems not working: in fact if I try to re-open the web socket the selected port is already in use.

```
> FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@41500094: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
```

If I try to connect to the WebSocket in fact my connection won't drop when I try to stop my producer and related Jetty server.

Instead if I kill and restart the whole application the first initialization works as expected.

My Producer code below:

```
class HttpEndpointActor() extends Producer{

  val wsComponent: WebsocketComponent =  new WebsocketComponent()
  wsComponent.setHost("localhost")
  wsComponent.setPort(2222)

  this.camelContext.addComponent("ws", wsComponent)

  override def endpointUri: String = "ws://localhost:2222/test?sendToAll=true"

  override def postStop() = {
    super.postStop()
    this.camelContext.getComponent("ws", classOf[WebsocketComponent]).doStop()
    this.camelContext.removeComponent("ws")
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Jetty? (be specific, as there are some websocket close bugs that might be affecting you)

Comment: It depends on the camel-websocket version (in my case 2.15.3) but from the logs I can see _jetty-8.1.17.v20150415_

Comment: Yeah ... wow ... [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), and the WebSocket implementation present on Jetty 8 from the early pre-final draft days of WebSocket.  While it does manage to have support for [RFC6455](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455), it only does so by sheer luck, and is actually not 100% compliant.  (Note: I maintain the WebSocket implementation on Jetty)

Comment: Oh.. As far I can see from the pom.xml of the camel component websocket, also in the last version 2.16.0, they use the same version of Jetty...